# Visual Studio code sync settings github gist ID

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, synchronization, settings

I'm using vs code's settings sync feature with my github account, but I can't find the gists anywhere on my github... Am I missing something ?

Comment: I can't find my gist for Settings Sync either. Did you figure out?

Comment: No still no idea where that thing is supposed to be located...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find your settings in GitHub because **Visual Studio doesn't store the synched settings in GitHub**. It uses **GitHub** as a way **to authenticate** you, but stores the settings somewhere else under their servers (in Azure, obviously) despite the authentication method you use.

In Windows, if you go to `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app` (I guess in Linux/macOS it would be the `/usr/share/code/resources/app` folder), there's a file called `product.json` that has a node called `configurationSync.store` with the URL used by VSCode to sync settings, despite the authentication method used:

[image: shows the mentioned settings]

As you can see, there's an URL `https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/` that actually is a CNAME to a `cloudapp.net` domain (at Azure), which is in charge of synching your settings in the end. It has a variant for the insider's build to test new sync features.

Comment: Of course ! I just assumed it would be on github from the identity provider selection... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the gists on Github or that particular gist? :)

You can force the update (check in the command palette, shift+alt+U on a Mac) or add these two in your settings.json for automatic update:

```
{
    "sync.quietSync": true,
    "sync.autoUpload": true
}
```

You will then find the gist created (click on your avatar, top right, and select "Your gists").

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for the answer. I can find the gists on github, but it's that particular gist that I can't find... The settings you mentioned are unknown in my setup... I think you are talking about the Settings Sync extension while I'm refering to the builtin settings sync feature (they have the same name yeah...). Am I right ?

Comment: Did you configure and synced? You can find those in the command palette, under Settings Sync, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, the sync is configured and works (tested across multiple devices) but I can't find the gist that's supposed to hold my settings on my github account !